# Is it possible to have Outlook 2013/2010 display an SPF warning?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spf

I have recently setup SPF and DKIM on my mail server. This works as expected, and during testing when sending emails to my gmail account, Gmail displays a warning if the addresses don't match or the mail server isn't authorized. It looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4tyD.png]

So far, I have not been able to configure Outlook 2010 or 2013 to show a similar warning. This is an important countermeasure for phishing attacks, and I would like to have Outlook clients show a warning if possible.

Is this something Outlook can do natively, or is there a third party tool available?